# Try-catch block in JavaCC grammar

Tags: java, parsing, javacc, parser-generator

I am trying to implement Error Reporting and Recovery in `JavaCC` grammar

I have mentioned the following code in `.jjt` grammar file

```
void Stm() :
{}
{
  try {
    (
      IfStm()
    |
      WhileStm()
    )
  }catch (ParseException e) {
    error_skipto(SEMICOLON);
  }
}


void error_skipto(int kind) {
  ParseException e = generateParseException();  // generate the exception object.
  System.out.println(e.toString());  // print the error message
  Token t;
  do {
    t = getNextToken();
  } while (t.kind != kind);
}
```

When I execute the command `jjtree CMinus.jjt` I get following error:

> Reading from file CMinus_ragu.jjt . . .
>   Error parsing input: org.javacc.jjtree.ParseException: Encountered " "{" "{ "" a
>   t line 111, column 30.
>   Was expecting one of:
>       "throws" ...
>       ":" ...
>       "#" ...

What is the error in the code and how should I handle the error recovery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword JAVACODE should be added before error handler code in grammar file. Therefore the method should appear as follows:

```
JAVACODE
void error_skipto(int kind) {
  ParseException e = generateParseException();  // generate the exception object.
  System.out.println(e.toString());  // print the error message
  Token t;
  do {
    t = getNextToken();
  } while (t.kind != kind);
}
```

This is because the keyword JAVACODE should be added before using java style production.